# JMeter use Variable as CSV File Location

Tags: csv, jmeter

In my JMeter test, I have a Loop Controller nested inside a few other modules with contains a CSV Data Set Config. I also have a CSV Data Set Config in the top of my Thread Group that reads from a CSV to get a file location. I was to use this file location in the nested CSV Data Set Confing to grab the CSV from that location and loop through that one. An error is being thrown because all the CSV files are loaded at once, in the beginning of the test. Is there a way to delay the loading of a CSV so that I can ensure the file path variable has already been set?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use CSV Data Set Config the way you describe. All the config elements get loaded before the test begins.

You can use Beanshell Pre/Post Processor/Sampler.

I had a requirement to load csv file in CSV Data set config of my JMeter script- Name of the csv file can be anything. I run my script with ANT. So i get the name from ANT and pass it to JMeter via a property. CSV data set config uses the property to load the CSV. Thought of sharing this as It might help you as I am not sure of your exact requirement.

EDIT:

You can have a look @ __CSVRead(), __StringFromFile() functions.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html